# Blender 2.8: link Render View to a single View Layer for rendering (multiple viewlayers, multiple cameras)

Tags: compositing-nodes, viewlayers

I've got several Collections (created with `bpy.data.collections.new()`), each consists of its own Area Light and multiple Cameras.
I've got a View Layer (`scene.view_layers.new()`) for each of the collections (all collections are `.exclude`d from the viewlayer except corresponding one).
I've got a `CompositorNodeRLayers` and several outputfile nodes for each View Layer.
I'm trying to render each View Layer from each of its Cameras.
I'm using stereo/multiview feature of blender:

```
    scene.render.use_multiview = True
    scene.render.views_format = 'MULTIVIEW'
```

and create a Render View for each camera: `scene.render.views.new()`.

In this setup `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` renders each view layer from *all* of the cameras even those that are not linked to any of view layer's collections (producing black images and combinatorially increasing rendering time)

---

Questions:

1. Can I link a Render View (elt of `scene.render.views`) to a View Layer (`scene.view_layers`)?
2. Otherwise, can I link a View Layer to a Camera?
3. Can I tell blender to skip cameras that are not in the object tree of a view layer being rendered?

Comment: Note that I could create different scenes, but then I'd have to call `render()` in a for-loop as many times as many view layers I currently have, no resources being reused between calls.

Comment: 1.Ask **one** question at a time. 2. Comments section is for **comments**

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth shall I edit this question anyhow or it's just a note to recall in the future?

Comment: An edit will be welcomed and this is for the future as well.